# onchange form submit not displaying result in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

In the select option, I used `onChange form submit` like below:

```
<form name="onchange" method="post" action="samepage.jsp">
    <select name="n1" onchange="document.onchange.submit()">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

After selecting an option, I can get the parameter of select option then I can use that parameter to get user names from database and all data will display at same page. It is working fine at eclipse but not showing user name (database values) in Internet Explorer. It is displaying blank. I want to display names without submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
document.forms['onchange'].submit();
```

Comment: Thank You , it is working fine and how can i learn like this script.

Comment: it is not working when i use submit button inside of same form, how can i get one form value to another form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`document.getElementsByName('onchange')[0].submit();`